# How to escape certain characters of a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a string `This is a Test` and a passed parameter `s`.
How can I escape all s-characters of that first string?

It should result in `Thi\s i\s a Te\sT`

I tried it like this:

```
rstr = rstr.replace(esc, r"\\" + esc)
```

But it will result in `\\` before each `s`

Comment: Actually, use simply `"\\"` instead of `r"\\"`. Making it a raw string means that \\ really does become \\, but you still can't end a string with a single backslash.

Answer (score 2):

`r'\\'` produces a literal double backslash:

```
>>> r'\\'
'\\\\'
```

Don't use a raw string here, just use `'\\'`:

```
>>> 'This is a Test'.replace('s', '\\s')
'Thi\\s i\\s a Te\\st'
```

Don't confuse the Python representation with the value. To make debugging and round-tripping easy, the Python interpreter uses the `repr()` function to echo back results.

The `repr()` of a string uses Python literal notation, including escaping any backslashes:

```
>>> r'\s'
'\\s'
>>> len(r'\s')
2
>>> print r'\s'
\s
```

The actual *value* contains just one backslash, but because a backslash can start characters with special meanings, such as `\n` (a newline), or `\x00` (a null byte), they are represented escaped so that you can paste the value directly back into the interpreter.